# Initialize one controller manually multiple times

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-controller

I manually initialize my controller as follow:

```
var body =  angular.element(document.body);
var injector = angular.element(body).injector();
var compile = injector.get('$compile');
var rootScope = injector.get('$rootScope');
var controller = injector.get('$controller');
var result = compile(ctrlElement)(rootScope);
var ctrlInstance = controller('MyCtrl', variables);
```

And everything works fine except when I initialize it twice with different variables. What happens is that if I run this code twice (on two different elements), both instances of MyCtrl will have the same variables.

How can I solve this problem? How can I initialize twice the same controller with different variables?

Comment: curious why you are going through these extra steps. Also doesn't make sense about controller because controllers aren't singletons they are standalone instances

Comment: @charlietfl long story short I use golden-layout and re-use controllers...

Comment: right but re-using controllers is common. What is `golden-layout`?

Comment: @charlietfl https://golden-layout.com

Comment: @charlietfl sorry for not being very verbose about the "why" but I don't think it will really help to solve the issue... I'm working on a quite complex webapp and it's not easy to detail all the reasons here

Comment: understood....looking at examples though they use mostly conventional angular module declarations

Comment: @charlietfl yes, I know... It took me a while to understand how to do it manually!

Comment: good luck...looks like you'll be in a forever uphill battle